# Can't get Celery task result in Django 1.11

Tags: python, ajax, django, celery

I want to get some Celery task result in django with AJAX. I have view like this:

```
def ajax_brand_count(request, task_id):
    extra_data = brand_count.AsyncResult(task_id)
    print("1", extra_data.state)
    print("2", extra_data.get())
    if extra_data.ready():
        print("3", extra_data)
        return HttpResponse('')
```

On **print 1** I get `SUCCESS`
On **print 2** I get `None`
On **print 3** I get a string which = `task_id`
I have `Redis` instance running.
I have `Celery` instance running with `SETTINGS`:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

In Terminal I see that task finishes successfully.
**What am I doing wrong?**
**UPDATE:**
I am using `Celery 3.1.25`.
My `task`, it returnes a `QuerySet`, which I want to render later in HTML:

```
@task(bind = True)
def brand_count(self, brand_ids):
    queryset = Brand.objects.filter(brand_id__in=brand_ids)
    queryset.annotate(amount_of_products=Count('products'))
```

Comment: What version of celery are you using? What does your task code return?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: The task code you have provided doesn't return a queryset. Did you just forget to add `return queryset` to your task?

Comment: Wow! this is the point! :) I am quite new to Celery and all tasks I used - didn't returned anything, so I thought that tasks might not have returns at all. If you want some points - write an answer, I will accept. P.S. `return serializers.serialize('json', queryset)` is required.

Comment: These are the best bugs :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've just forgotten to `return` the result of the task at the end of your task definition. Add `return queryset` to the end of your task and hopefully it will all work!